# JS converting using Uint8Array double value convert it to float

Tags: javascript, binary, uint8array

Im sending using HTML5 web sockets object movement , then i convert this value using Uint8Array .
the problem is the value im getting when moving the object is double 
after doing the convert im getting float value .
Here is the example: 
     The initial value :

```
player_x:633.8823529411765
player_y:412.235294117647



_stringConvertToUint8Array:function (strData) {  
    // View the byte buffer as an array of 8-bit unsigned integers
    var arrData = new Uint8Array(strData.length);
    for (var i=0;i<strData.length;++i) {
        arrData[i] = strData.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    // Log the binary array
    cc.log("SEND ARRAY BUFFER: " + arrData.buffer);
    return arrData;
},
sendMassage: function(reqJson)
{
    if (this.m_wsiSendBinary.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN)
    {

        var buf = Encode(reqJson);
        var binary = this._stringConvertToUint8Array(buf);
        this.m_wsiSendBinary.send(binary.buffer);
    }
    else
    {
        var warningStr = "send binary websocket instance wasn't ready...";

        }
    },
```

result of the print

```
SEND ARRAY BUFFER: [object ArrayBuffer]
Websockts.js?_t=1469105183221:30 {   
    "player_y": 412.235294,
    "player_x": 633.882353
}
```

Comment: Javascript has neither `double` nor `float` type. Only [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Data_types) which include all number types

Comment: ok so i guess i need to ask why does it remove the precision after the point

Comment: I guess the problem is on the server side where you send data.

Comment: i fixed it using player_x = (player_x).toFixed(6)/1;